# Return only one Boolean Row in Cypher instead of Null

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a graph with nodes like 'Persons' and relationships called 'RELATION' with a dynamic type like 'BIOLOGICAL_MOTHER'.

**To check if a person is in a parent-role i want to use one cypher-query that return one boolean row, instead of NULL or something else.**

I use Spring Data Neo4j 4 and this is the following method in the person-repository:

```
@Query("OPTIONAL MATCH (child)-[r:RELATION]->(parent) " +
        "RETURN DISTINCT " +
        "CASE " +
        "WHEN id(parent)={0} AND r IS NOT NULL AND (r.type='BIOLOGICAL_MOTHER' OR r.type='BIOLOGICAL_FATHER') " +
        "THEN true " +
        "ELSE false " +
        "END")
boolean isParentRole(long id);
```

If i query this on a parent person, the following error returns :

```
More than one element in org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper
$MyIteratorWrapper@235ecd9f. 
First element is 'true' and the second element is 'false'
```

**How can i use "OR" of all result-rows, to return only one row (in this case true)?**

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with this query:

```
@Query("OPTIONAL MATCH (child)-[r:RELATION]->(parent) " +
        "WITH (CASE WHEN id(parent)={0} AND r IS NOT NULL " +
        "AND (r.type='BIOLOGICAL_MOTHER' OR r.type='BIOLOGICAL_FATHER') THEN true ELSE false END) as check " +
        "RETURN ANY (x in collect(check) WHERE x=true) ")
boolean isParentRole(long id);
```

If an easier way solve my problem, please comment.